# How can I save a column in a table and check if there is Text in each of the cells in the Robot Framework Selenium?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I plan to create a For for the cell of the table and save the content, to preguantar with an IF if it has Text or not.

But I do not know how a For and an IF within a Table work.

```
Verificar Recibo Pagado
    ${Texto} = Get Table Cell ${Tabla} 11 9
    Run Keyword If ${Texto}
    log ${Texto}
```

Comment: Although it's a small example and the meaning of the text can be deduced, it is better to use only English in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Nice to see Spanish usage in your test case. :)*

To verify table data, we need to do nested loop logically. But we can't write nested loop directly in Robot Framework. We can make separate keyword for innerloop and we can call it in main for loop.

**For.e.g.,**

If your  variable `${Tabla}` refers to xpath as `//table[@id='some id']` and all rows has same columns, Then test case to verify no empty data in cells will be as below,

```
*** Variables ***
${Tabla}    //table[@id='some id']

*** Test Cases ***
Verificar Recibo Pagado
   ${fila} =    Get Element Count   ${Tabla}/tbody/tr   # Get row count
   :FOR    ${rowindex}    IN RANGE    1    ${fila + 1}
    \    All Column Should Not Be Empty  ${Tabla}   ${rowindex}

*** Keywords ***
All Column Should Not Be Empty 
    [Arguments]    ${Tabla}    ${fila}
    ${columna} =    Get Element Count   ${Tabla}/tbody/tr/td   # Get Column count
    :FOR    ${colindex}    IN RANGE    1    ${columna + 1}
    \    ${Texto} = Get Table Cell  ${Tabla}   ${fila}   ${colindex}
    \    Should Not Be Empty  ${Texto}
```